# Windows Service requires stop and start to reset configuration

Tags: .net, windows, service

I'm working with several third-party apps which run as a Windows Service and their support always tells us to restart the service to utilize changes in the configuration (Some use an .xml doc, and some are in the database managed by the applications administrative GUI). When it doesn't work, they clarify and tell us to Stop and then Start the service. Restart doesn't work.

[image]

Hope the picture helps. I'm referring to:
1. Start 
2. Stop
3. Restart

I'm not concerned with administrating their app. We just do what they tell us to do. I'm wondering if there is a reason for developing a service app this way? is this a limitation of Windows Services, .NET or just the way it was coded? If the developers have no choice, I wouldn't suggest they change it.

Comment: There is no "restart" option for Windows services.  When you use that option in the Services control panel, it stops the service and then starts it again.  If that makes any difference, well, there's something wrong with the service, probably a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Services read the appropriate app.config file at start up and cache the contents, and the only way to use new configuration values is to restart the service.

From your question it would appear that the 3rd Party software vendor has simply followed the same convention with their Database & XML configuration settings.

So is this normal, typically yes. Can this be adjusted, possibly (but I would question the ROI when making such a decision).

Comment: When you say "Restart" are you talking about clicking the Restart button (which doesn't work) or having to use the Stop and Start buttons in the Service GUI?

Comment: The ROI is how many service calls do you want to handle because admins restart the service and then you have to follow-up only to realize they needed to stop and start the service.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer stop and start. However it's puzzling that restart doesn't work as it was my understanding restart stopped then started a service in a serial manner. Obviously my assumption was wrong.

Comment: No, I don't think you're wrong.  Perhaps the service in question has a race condition and doesn't behave properly if it is started too quickly after it is stopped.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Sounds like an answer.